# Format a string to only lowercase letters and underscores to make it usable for URLs in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create sanitized URLs slugs from title field written by users. The input will be something like:

```js
const title = 'Puede àgregar unÁ imagen en miniatura (JPG, PNG, GIF) a tu_publicación-que *hola* #@\÷@¡'¿¸˛¸ aparecerá en todas las listas del foro. Debe ser una URL de imagen válida, nosotros nos encargamos de cambiarle el tamaño.'
```

And i need to generate a string that is sanitized like this:

```js
'puede_agregar_una_imagen_en_miniatura_jpg_png_gif_a_tu_publicacion_que_hola_aparecera_en_todas_las_listas_del_foro_debe_ser_una_URL_de_imagen_valida_nosotros_nos_encargamos_de_cambiarle_el_tamano'
```

I tried to use `replace()` method but once I get into the regex part i cannot figure out how to match more than spaces.

```js
title.replace(/[\s-,*()#$%]/g, '_').toLocaleLowerCase()
```

I want to be able to replace:

- All symbols (*,) to nothing.
- All - to _
- All spaces to underlines '_'
- All áóúíéèàòù, etc. to normalized lettters.
- other characters like ñ should be replaced to n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you evaluated if [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) fits your needs? Altthough not replacing characters as you want, it still makes sure strings are URL safe which I understand as the primary goal.

Comment: to do what you want `title.replace(/(\s|-)/g, '_').normalize('NFKD').replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase()`